# Rust PathBuf issues when building relative dir from home

Tags: rust

```
static CONFIG_FILE: &str = "/.config/myapp/config.toml";
```

but I want to build an os agnostic path:

`$HOME/.config/myapp/config.toml`

Tried variations of:

```
static CONFIG_FILE: &str = dirs::home_dir().unwrap().join(".config").join("myapp").join("config.toml").to_str().unwrap();
```

but I get:

```
   |
28 | static  CONFIG_FILE: &str = dirs::home_dir().unwrap().join(".config").join("myapp").join("config.toml").to_str().unwrap();
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `~const Deref` is not implemented for `PathBuf`
```

The following seems to compile however the end part of the path is not platform agnostic.

```
/// Application configuration filename
static HOME: Lazy<String> = Lazy::new(|| { env::var("HOME").unwrap() } );
static CONFIG_FILE: Lazy<PathBuf> = Lazy::new(||{Path::new(&HOME.as_str()).join(".config/assimilate/config.toml")});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the methods involved aren't `const`. You should be able to assemble the string with [`std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR.html)([`_STR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR_STR.html)), but [`home_dir`](https://docs.rs/dirs/latest/dirs/fn.home_dir.html) is very much not `const`. Are you able to use [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) instead?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Prefer `once_cell` to `lazy_static`.

Comment: https://github.com/microscaler/assimilate/blob/e714b75ed728fca3653dfd23dc3e891e0553a4f7/src/commands.rs#L28

This is the link to what I was trying to do

Comment: @casibbald I can't access the repository. Is it private?

Comment: I have made the repo public:

The following seems to work, however the concatenated paths are not platform agnostic
```
/// Application configuration filename
static HOME: Lazy<String> = Lazy::new(|| { env::var("HOME").unwrap() } );
static CONFIG_FILE: Lazy<PathBuf> = Lazy::new(||{Path::new(&HOME.as_str()).join(".config/assimilate/config.toml")});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```rs
static CONFIG_FILE: Lazy<PathBuf> = Lazy::new(||{dirs::home_dir().unwrap().join(".config").join("myapp").join("config.toml")});
```

Comment: So this worked as it wanted PathBuff, did not like the to_str()

```
static CONFIG_FILE: Lazy<PathBuf> = Lazy::new(||{dirs::home_dir().unwrap().join(".config").join("myapp").join("config.toml")});
```

Thanks so much Solomon